# WordPress - Deferring third party script

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, hubspot

I have a WordPress site that is using Advanced Custom Fields to render content. One such field allows users to add third party form code.

Recently users have been using HubSpot forms and this is hurting page load times.

One such example is the code below.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2-legacy.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js"></script>
<script>

hbspt.forms.create({
    region: "na1",
    portalId: "8142945",
    formId: "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
});
</script>
```

The users enters this and it is rendered in place like so:

[image]

Is there a way that the user can copy the embed code and then I can defer it, or at least load it last?

I was thinking of just adding defer and then wrapping the form creation call in an onload event, but that would then mean that the user would need to wrap everything they past in correctly.

Has anyone dealt with a similar situation?

One solution could be to make them enter the form ID only and then I add or remove script as necessary?

Comment: The v2.js file has already deferred. I can't understand what do you want! Please clarify it.

Comment: Hi, I'm just thinking adding random extra attributes to scripts may be a bit awkward for end users.